# Udemy Selenium Tutorial - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"btnk"}

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, attributeerror

I have EXACTLY (character, spacing indentation) what the instructor has in the Udemy tutorial. His test is running fine but mine is getting errors. Please review below. Thanks!

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_search(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()
        x = self.driver.title
        print(x)
        self.assertEqual(x, "Automation step by step")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
```

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()

File "C:\Users\S-Iran\PycharmProjects\Demo\Demo_1\utest1.py", line 15, in test_search
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()

File "C:\Users\S-Iran\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)

File "C:\Users\S-Iran\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

File "C:\Users\S-Iran\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Users\S-Iran\PycharmProjects\Demo\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"btnk"}
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Your "setup" function should be called "setUp" in order to be invoke first

Comment: Thank you so much! Did you notice that from the errors? Or Just off reading the method?

Now I have different errors. I inspected the elements on Google and they still have the correct names so I'm not sure why they can't be found.

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"btnk"}

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: In your html there is no element named "btnk", it is pretty straight forward

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My question is why is it saying that. When I go to google right now and inspect the search button the name is "btnk". As I said, I'm following a Udemy video step by step so I don't understand why it's working for him and not me. I don't care if I use a different selector and it works. I just want to know why I need to do that and he doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of click on button which is not present when you do `sendKeys` you can use `element.submit()`

Instead of this.

```
self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation step by step")
  self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()
```

Try this.

```
element=self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
element.send_keys("Automation step by step")
element.submit()
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this the preferred method?

Comment: Yes.Can you accept my answer by clicking accept to my code message.